# reset serial number in every page of rdlc report

Tags: vb.net

I have used RowNumber(Nothing) in sl column. The serial number is increasing as much the row quantity. But I need to reset the serial number in every page.

I have used only one row group. I do not want to reset serial in row group, but only in every page.

Please give me suggestion about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain what you have tried till now.

Comment: Tried to use RowNumber(Nothing) in Sl Textbox of the table.

Comment: I also tried to use sl number from my DB. I tried to set sl to zero when it reached at 9. but sometimes my report shows 9 rows in a page and sometimes more. And I need to start sl from zero.